# Odoo payslip with leave in salary rule python code

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have to calculate the basic pay with if condition.if the employee does not have unpaid leave means Unpaid is not there under Worked days and input under payslip then unpaid leave should be o(Zero).
    I have tried the below code but its given error.

```
day=contract.wage/30
if not worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days in payslip:
      result=day*(30-0)
else:
      result=day*(30-worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in command in python is used to check for membership.
E.g. : `3 in [1, 2, 3]` results in True.
I am not exactly sure what is the purpose of payslip in your code but from what I understand you may try this:

```
day=contract.wage/30
if Not(worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days):
    result=day*(30-0)
else:
    result=day*(30-worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days)
```

Edit after comments :

```
day=contract.wage/30
if worked_days.Unpaid and worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days or False:
    result=day*(30-0)
else:
    result=day*(30-worked_days.Unpaid.number_of_days)
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but still not working.I want if condition to check whether employee has taken unpaid leave.

Comment: Wrong python code defined for salary rule Basic (BASIC).

Comment: Thank a lot it got worked.I have done some minor changes in your code and it worked for me.

Comment: Great. Please accept or up vote my answer! Thank you!

Comment: @shravya shetty Can you please upload the changes that you have done for the code

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this blog for detail payslip rule to deduct the unpaid leaves and its calculations and configurations [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXkaKl1eLUAhXJqo8KHU2qCeQQFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cybrosys.com%2Fblog%2Fhr-unpaid-leaves-payroll-management-in-odoo-10&usg=AFQjCNHM5sebSC6NkBZ0EurQiYJIaNozxQ)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Friends I am also facing the same problem but I Got solution to get number_of_days without facing error and calculate Deduction against Contract From salary.**

**To get number_of_days payable from payslip**

```
number_of_days = 0

for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
    number_of_days += line.number_of_days
```

**calculate DAC (Salary Deduction Against Contract)**

```
if contract.deduct_salary_from_payslip == True:
    if payslip.date_from <= employee.joining_date and employee.joining_date <= payslip.date_to:
        result = -(number_of_days*(contract.wage/30))*.10
    else:
        result = -(contract.wage * 0.10)
else:
    result=0.0
```

I think This code Will help you solve the Problem that you are facing while calculating Deduction or allowances For Payslip.